# No consigo compilar una app para Android ni con Cordova ni con PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, phonegap

Hasta ahora siempre he usado para compilar las aplicaciones [PhoneGapBuild](https://build.phonegap.com/) y todo iba bien hasta que la web ha dejado de funcionar y no dan soporte.
He pasado a compilar la app desde la linea de comandos , pero me resulta imposible me da siempre este error desde :

```
* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:

  Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.

  Program type already present: android.support.v13.view.DragStartHelper$1


* Try:

Run with --stacktrace  option to get the stack trace. Run with --info  or --debug  option to get more log output. Run with --scan  to get full insights.


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org



BUILD FAILED  in 35s

35 actionable tasks: 35 executed

C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Apps
-PhoneGap\xxxxxx-app-xxxxx\App\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. D8: Program type already present: android.support.v13.view.DragStartHelper$1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:   Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes. Program type already present: android.support.v13.view.DragStartHelper$1

* Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 35s
```

Este es mi config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="es.xxxxx.xxxxxxxx" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <name>xxxxxx</name>
    <description>
       xxxxxx
    </description>
    <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
        PhoneGap Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
  <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-9.0.0"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" />
  <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
  <preference name="resizeOnFullScreen" value="false" />
  

  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" source="npm"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" source="npm" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts" source="npm"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-motion" source="npm"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" source="npm" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" source="npm"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" source="npm"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" source="npm"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" source="npm"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" source="npm"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-evcore-extbuild-free" source="npm" />

    <platform name="android">
      <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
        <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
      </edit-config>
      
      <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="app/google-services.json" />
.....
.....
.....
</widget>
```

Alguna idea de que estoy haciendo mal?
Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Por si a alguien le sirve:
1.- Borrar todo lo que hay dentro de la carpeta `plugins` del proyecto
2.- Borrar las plataformas de la carpeta `platforms` del proyecto
3.- Desde la consola de comandos navegar a la raíz del proyecto y escribir

> cordova platform add android

> cordova build android

Comment: bien jugado JoCuTo no ken :D